# Unable to install 'Tensorflow Federated' on Apple Silicon M1

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1, tensorflow-federated

I have TensorFlow (2.8.0) installed and running on my Apple Silicon M1 MacBook. But facing dependency error on trying to install tensorflow-federated with the below error on running `pip install tensorflow-federated` in terminal :

```
ERROR: Cannot install tensorflow-federated==0.1.0, tensorflow-federated==0.10.0, tensorflow-federated==0.10.1, tensorflow-federated==0.11.0, tensorflow-federated==0.12.0, tensorflow-federated==0.13.0, tensorflow-federated==0.13.1, tensorflow-federated==0.14.0, tensorflow-federated==0.15.0, tensorflow-federated==0.16.0, tensorflow-federated==0.16.1, tensorflow-federated==0.17.0, tensorflow-federated==0.18.0, tensorflow-federated==0.19.0, tensorflow-federated==0.2.0, tensorflow-federated==0.20.0, tensorflow-federated==0.21.0, tensorflow-federated==0.22.0, tensorflow-federated==0.3.0, tensorflow-federated==0.4.0, tensorflow-federated==0.5.0, tensorflow-federated==0.6.0, tensorflow-federated==0.7.0 and tensorflow-federated==0.9.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tensorflow-federated 0.22.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.8.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.21.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.8.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.20.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.8.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.19.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.5.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.18.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.12.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.17.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.3.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.16.1 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.10.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.16.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.10.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.15.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.10.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.14.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.2.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.13.1 depends on tensorflow~=2.1.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.13.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.1.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.12.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.1.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.11.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.6.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.10.1 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.6.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.10.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.6.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.9.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.7.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.6.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.5.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.4.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.3.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.2.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.1.0 depends on tensorflow>=1.13.0rc2

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Comment: Uninstall tensorflow and install  tensorflow-federated

Answer (score 0):

Could you follow the instructions for M1 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) to install Tensorflow and it's dependencies on a new virtual environment and then install the `tensorflow-federated`.
I was successfully able to install tensorflow-federated along with all it's dependencies mentioned below on my M1 with Tensorflow 2.8 version.

```
Successfully installed attrs-21.2.0 cachetools-3.1.1 cloudpickle-2.0.0 cycler-0.11.0 decorator-5.1.1 dill-0.3.4 dm-tree-0.1.7 farmhashpy-0.4.0 
googleapis-common-protos-1.56.1 grpcio-1.34.1 importlib-resources-5.7.1
jax-0.2.28 jaxlib-0.1.76 joblib-1.1.0 kiwisolver-1.4.2 kubernetes-21.7.0
matplotlib-3.3.4 numpy-1.21.6 pandas-1.1.5 pillow-9.1.1 portpicker-1.3.
promise-2.3 pyparsing-3.0.9 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.1 pyyaml-6.0 
scikit-learn-1.0.2 scipy-1.5.4 semantic-version-2.8.5 tensorflow-2.8.1 
tensorflow-datasets-4.5.2 tensorflow-estimator-2.8.0 tensorflow-federated-0.24.0 
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.26.0 tensorflow-metadata-1.8.0 
tensorflow-model-optimization-0.7.2 tensorflow-privacy-0.8.0 
tensorflow-probability-0.15.0 threadpoolctl-3.1.0 tqdm-4.28.1 websocket-client-1.3.2
```